# plotting histogram with personalized classes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

first time using python
I already plotted histogram using option 'bins'

```py
plt.hist(data['salary'], bins = 10)
```

bins divide the total interval linearly.
that means, if salary in [0,1000[ then we got 10 intervals [0,100[, [100,200[ ... [900,1000[ in case using bins = 10.
But what if I want to divide [0,1000[ into only 3 intervals [0,500[, [500,900[
and [900,1000[ 
Any solution ??

Comment: Please fix your brackets, and [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`matplotlib` docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

> bins : int or **sequence** or str, optional
>
> - If an integer is given, bins + 1 bin edges are calculated and returned, consistent with numpy.histogram.
> - If bins is a sequence, gives bin edges, including left edge of first bin and right edge of last bin. In this case, bins is returned unmodified.

Specify: `bins=[0, 500, 900, 1000]`, which will give you the bins: [0, 100), [500, 900), [900, 1000]. Notice all bins but the last are half-open.